# "and return unless nil" statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
def test
  show_msg and return unless nil
  puts "This line can not be executed"
end

def show_msg
 puts "exit here"
end

test
```

Output:

```
exit here
This line can not be executed
```

I expected the only on line:

```
exit here
```

Why?

Comment: By the way, your `return` on the first line of `test` will not be executed because `show_msg` returns `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

as said in the comments, this doesn't work because `puts` actually [returns nil](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts), so you can either explictly return something from your `show_msg` function, or either use `p` for instance

```
def test
  show_msg and return unless nil
  puts "This line can not be executed"
end

def show_msg
 p "exit here"
end

test
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `unless nil`; that's a no-op, because `nil` will never be a true value. (In Ruby, `nil` is the one value besides `false` itself that is considered false in a Boolean truth-test context.  It's confusing to say that `nil` "is false", when it is not equal to `false`, so Rubyists instead say that `nil` is "falsey").

Anyway, `return unless nil` is the same as plain `return`.

Your `show_msg` method, lacking an explicit `return` statement, will return the value of the last statement in it.  That statement is a `puts`, which returns `nil`.  So `show_msg` also returns `nil`, and since `nil` is falsey, the `and` short-circuits before it gets to the `return`.  Therefore, the `return` is not executed and Ruby continues on to the next line and executes it.

Comment: It's just a syntetic test. In real it is: **show_msg and return unless @variable**